# indexPath.row is always 0

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath

I'm working on populating the table view with an array of dictionaries. The contents of the arrays and the dictionaries are parsed without problems. However, the table is populated with [array count] number of cells with contents with index 0 of the array. It seems to me that indexPath.row returns 0 for all cells. How do I populate each cell with the corresponding index?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


// Configure the cell...
NSDictionary *term = [self.terms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [term objectForKey:@"content"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [term objectForKey:@"created"];

return cell;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Here's what I got for logging indexPath

> 2011-11-21 03:07:58.025 Demo[21269:f803]  2
>   indexes [0, 0]
>
> 2011-11-21 03:07:58.027 Demo[21269:f803]  2
>   indexes [1, 0]

Seems like the first index is updating while the second is not.

When I logged indexPath.row, however

> 2011-11-21 03:19:40.306 Demo[21546:f803] 0
>
> 2011-11-21 03:19:40.308 Demo[21546:f803] 0

So what should I use to get the value that is incrementing?

Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That block of code looks fine in itself.  Maybe your tableview has multiple sections with one row each?  What are you returning for the datasource methods `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` (should be `[self.terms count]` 
) and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` (should be 1).

If those are OK, put `NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);` somewhere in the method and post the output into your question.

Comment: Here's what I have for logging indexPath:
2011-11-21 03:07:58.025 Demo[21269:f803] 2 indexes [0, 0]

2011-11-21 03:07:58.027 Demo[21269:f803] 2 indexes [1, 0]

I have only one section to my table and I'm returning the right values for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

Comment: @SimonLee - the logging you are seeing says the table view is asking for section 0, row 0, then section 1, row 0. So I don't think you do have the right implementation for your rows and sections methods - can you include those in the question?

Comment: @jrturton Thanks for the heads up! Turns out I implemented rows in sections and sections in rows. Everything work fine after I switched them. Stupid mistake!

Comment: @SimonLee you should accept David's answer then, he was correct.

Comment: What the F :D Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 15):

I have just had a similar issue (indexPath.row was always 0) and noticed how much of an idiot I was. In my `numberOfSectionsInTableView` I was returning the `[dataSet count]` and in my `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` I was returning 1. Should be the other way around. Oops!